# Disable short polling for RTK Query on window not focused and revalidate on resume focus

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I am using Redux Toolkit with RTK Query to manage the API calls and states in my React application.

For a particular API, I am trying to mimic a real-time update effect with short polling, and calling the API defined in the API reducer by,

```
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetAPIQuery(
    {},
    { pollingInterval: 5000 }
  );
```

However, I want the short polling to stop when the user has left the window, such as switching the focused tab to another tab, and revalidating the data once the window is focused again.

Is this possible with RTK query?

Similiar question also asked as issue posted on [Github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RTK version 2.1.0 there is now a built-in `skipPollingIfUnfocused` option.

Example copied from the docs:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } from './services/pokemon'

export const Pokemon = ({ name }: { name: string }) => {
  // Automatically refetch every 3s unless the window is out of focus
  const { data, status, error, refetch } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery(name, {
    pollingInterval: 3000,
    skipPollingIfUnfocused: true,
  })

  return <div>{data}</div>
}
```

[Release notes](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases/tag/v2.1.0).

[Docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/polling#:%7E:text=Polling%20additionally%20has,have%20been%20called.)

Comment: That’s great to know, can you add a code sample and I’ll mark this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a package like `use-window-focus` to detect the focus.

```js
  const windowFocused = useWindowFocus();
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetAPIQuery(
    {},
    { pollingInterval: windowFocused  ? 5000 : false }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update 05 Feb 2024

RTK quer has added a new option called `skipPollingIfUnfocused`, refer to [dipea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77927869/12569596) for the updated usage

---

## Original answer (outdated)

I found out about the conditional fetching in the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching)

we can use a hook to check if the window is in focus, for example the `use-window-focus` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-window-focus)

then pass this boolean into the `skip` option, and the page will be automatically and immediately revalidaite on window refocus

```
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetAPIQuery(
    {},
    { pollingInterval: 5000, skip: isWindowFocused }
  );
```